# Snippets breaking on one entry, but not others?

Tags: templates, comments

What would cause an EE template to barf on one set of comments but not another?

For example, the comments on this page are messed up:

http://alistapart.com/comments/seo

But it doesn't seem to be happening on any other article (that we've found). Example:

http://alistapart.com/comments/negativemargins

What could cause this? I've gone through the comments to see if I could spot any bad code, but even if I had found something I'm at a loss to explain why it would cause problems with EE rendering.

(EECMS v 2.5.5)

Comment: Can you show us the template code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this page is breaking because of the edit comment functionality combined with PHP/HTML in a comment.

See [comment #322268](http://alistapart.com/comments/seo#322268): he's got PHP-style and HTML tags in his comment, which all seem to be escaped properly, but when that same comment content is replicated in the hidden block for comment editing (.edit-comment), your page source code is abruptly cut off.

Since this is affecting the rending of EE conditionals on the page, I assume the choke is happening server-side - EE isn't liking the `<?` and `?>` entities inside of the the template's tagdata, and is choking on them.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that. I thought I had closed that comment, but I didn't confirm it was gone, and it looks like the same problem was affecting the control panel and preventing it from being closed. Thanks!